# How to merge an updated upstream into a topic branch automatically?

Tags: git, merge

The scenario is:

At first branch A and B have the same commit history, later A adds commit `a`, B adds commit `b`.

1. in Git 1.7.0.4, running `git merge [--no-ff] B` on branch A will automatically generate the merge commit with message "Merge branch 'B' into A"
2. in Git 1.8.1.5, running `git merge [--no-ff] B` on branch A opens my editor, and I have to manually add/modify merge message to finish merge

Of course, I can add the "-m" parameter to 'git merge' to avoid invoke the editor, but this method is a little annoying.

Is there anyone way to set global configuration to automatically generate the merge commit ?

This is the message shown when the editor is opened:

> Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.

Comment: Note that it's a good practise to customize merge commit messages, as you can summarize the feature/bugfix you're merging in. If you're merging an update upstream, you might want to consider a rebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git merge --no-edit B
```

or

```
GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no git merge B
```

These are both documented in the [manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) for `git merge`.

Comment: so you mean i have to add GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no before each "git merge " ?

Comment: what i want is to set 'merge autoedit to no' once and for all,and later i don't have to add '--no-edit' each time using 'git merge'

Comment: @Venus, do `git config --global alias.nmerge "merge --no-edit"`, then you can `git nmerge B` and the option will be applied